# Static files works only on default endpoint ASP NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Problem is that static files loads only on default endpoint .
If I type endpoint route manually static files won't load
I add ~ character to every script tag but it won't works
[Same Page but on endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnW1m.jpg)

[When Type same controller and action on URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUpcK.jpg)

**Startup.cs**

````
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                        .AllowAnyHeader());
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
 
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Customer}/{action=Customers}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}```



Thank you for your advice
````

Comment: Show an example of you using a static file.

Comment: Scripts Partial 
<script src="~/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

Comment: Don't add to the comments, [edit] your question with the detail. Also make sure you explain where those files are in your structure.

Comment: Hi @FarHard112, it works well in my project although I change the url for different controller and action. Where did you add code for rendering such image and could you please share the code? Could you please share your project structure for static file?

Comment: <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
<div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
    <div class="image">
        @*<img src="~/img/logoPak/pakXalca.png" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">*@
        <i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size: 3em" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <p style="margin-top:12px"><strong style="color: white"> User Name</strong> </p>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: Hi @FarHard112, please follow what DavidG said to edit question instead of sharing code in comment. Besides, where is your `img/logoPak/pakXalca.png`? Does it locate in wwwroot folder? Also where is the code located, in _Layout.cshtml or other cshtml files?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was : When adding path some file I forget add ~(tilda)
It dumb but its true